# If $g\circ f$ is proper and $f$ is surjective then $g$ is proper (specific definition of properness)

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : X \to X', g: X' \to X''$ be continous functinos on topological spaces. If $gf$ is a proper map and $f$ is surjective, I want to check that $g$ must be proper.

**I'm interested in solving this exercise by showing that $g \times 1_Z$ is closed for every topological space $Z$, as that is the definition we are using.**

I know that $gf \times 1_Z = (g \times 1_Z) \circ (f \times 1_Z)$, and if $f \times 1_Z$ was surjective, then I'd know how to finish the exercise, but it isn't.

What I would like to do is the following: given $H$ closed in $X' \times Z$, I want to build a closed set $K$ in $X \times Z$ such that $f \times 1_Z (K) = H$. I'm having trouble proving that I can build a closed $H$ like that. In fact, I don't know if I can.

Could someone please give me any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a compact subset of $X"$, $(g\circ f)^{-1}=A$ is a compact subset since $g\circ f$ is proper, since $f$ is continuous, $f(A)$ is compact, $f(A)=g^{-1}(C)$ since $f$ is surjective.

Let $C$ be a closed subset of $Z\times X'$ since $f$ is surjective, $C=(Id_Z\times f)(Id_Z\times f)^{-1}(C))$, write $B=(Id_Z\times f)^{-1}(C)$, it is closed, you deduce that $Id_Z\times gf)(B)=(Id_Z\times g)(C)$ is closed.

Comment: Notice that I'm asking especifically for another (equivalent) definition of properness.